# What is the alternative for source command in cmd?

Tags: windows-7, windows, python, cmd.exe, virtualenv

I want to run the Windows (Command Prompt) equivalent of

```
source myvenv/bin/activate
```

so as to activate and enter into my virtual environment.

Comment: Batch file can automate what you want, but you need to know what `activate` does, and translate it accordingly.

Comment: Well I do not have any idea how to do this :/

Comment: If you have solved the problem, please post your answer ***as an answer*** in the “Your Answer” box (below).

Answer (score 7):

At CMD prompt,it worked by running

```
myvenv\scripts\activate.bat
```

Comment: Given this self-answer, the asker appears to be using [vanilla Python](https://www.python.org) and virtual environments created with `python -m venv some-environment` (rather than, say, using `conda`).

Comment: Specific to your question "What is the alternative for source command in cmd?"  The equivalent command to "source" is "call".. but it is only used from another batch file.

Comment: "The system cannot find the path specified." - not helpful.

Answer (score 4):

For activating an environment:

```
activate myenv
```

for deactivating (all)

```
deactivate
```

Comment: not working says 'activate' not a recognized command

Comment: Did you used `conda` for creating your environments? Try the command `conda` from your cmd window.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the the directory where you have the ".bat" file by executing this command:

> C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\ProjectsWork\FlaskApplication> cd env\Scripts

Then just call the ".bat" file

> \Desktop\ProjectsWork\FlaskApplication\env\Scripts> activate.bat

**(env) C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\ProjectsWork\FlaskApplication\env\Scripts>**

Comment: this is the most straightforward and correct answer...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your environment in batch file then

`call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`

All the following command will be executed in virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to activate your virtual environment after running:

```
virtualenv env
```

Just run:

```
env\Scripts\activate
```

This command will provide you the correct path and the command "source" is not necessary.

[image: Example Image]